# Asp.net Core get "Back-off restarting failed container" on AKS

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy my very first and simple ASP.net Core Web Api on the AKS (ref to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/containerized-lifecycle/design-develop-containerized-apps/build-aspnet-core-applications-linux-containers-aks-kubernetes))

Here is my yaml file

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: aexp
  labels:
    app: aexp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: aexp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: aexp
        service: aexp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: aexp
          image: f2021.azurecr.io/aexp:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: http://+:80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aexp
  labels:
    app: aexp
    service: aexp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    service: aexp
```

It looks simple and straightforward, but I couldn't figure out why my pod gets Back-off restarting failed container. Any advice a clue to prevent the error? thanks in advance.

```html
Name:         aexp-5b5b7b6464-5lfz4
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-nodepool1-38572550-vmss000000/10.240.0.4
Start Time:   Wed, 20 Jan 2021 10:01:52 +0700
Labels:       app=aexp
              pod-template-hash=5b5b7b6464
              service=aexp
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.14
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.14
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/aexp-5b5b7b6464
Containers:
  aexp:
    Container ID:   docker://25ffdb3ce92eeda465e1971daa363d6f532ac73ff82df2e9b3694a8949f50615
    Image:          f2021.azurecr.io/aexp:v1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://f2021.azurecr.io/aexp@sha256:bf6aa2a47f5f857878280f5987192f1892e91e365b9e66df83538109b9e57c46
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 20 Jan 2021 10:33:47 +0700
      Finished:     Wed, 20 Jan 2021 10:33:47 +0700
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  11
    Environment:
      ASPNETCORE_URLS:  http://+:80
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-g4ks9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-g4ks9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-g4ks9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  36m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/aexp-5b5b7b6464-5lfz4 to aks-nodepool1-38572550-vmss000000
  Normal   Pulled     35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "f2021.azurecr.io/aexp:v1"
  Normal   Created    35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet            Created container aexp
  Normal   Started    35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet            Started container aexp
  Normal   Pulling    34m (x5 over 36m)    kubelet            Pulling image "f2021.azurecr.io/aexp:v1"
  Warning  BackOff    62s (x166 over 36m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

And here is my az snippet to create AKS cluster

```html
az aks create \
  --location $REGION \
  --resource-group $AKS_RG \
  --name $AKS_NAME \
  --ssh-key-value ./.ssh/id_rsa.pub \
  --service-principal "xxxxxxxx-b8d1-4206-8a8a-xxxxx66c086c" \
  --client-secret "xxxx.xxxxeNzq25iJeuRjWTh~xxxxxUGxu" \
  --network-plugin kubenet \
  --load-balancer-sku basic \
  --outbound-type loadBalancer \
  --node-vm-size Standard_B2s \
  --node-count 1 \
  --tags 'ENV=DEV' 'SRV=EXAMPLE'  \
  --generate-ssh-keys
```

Update 1:
I try with VS2019, start Debug using “Bridge to Kubernetes”, then it works, the same docker image, same deployment and same service.

Update 2: add docker file

```html
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Aexp/Aexp.csproj", "Aexp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Aexp/Aexp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Aexp"
RUN dotnet build "Aexp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Aexp.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Aexp.dll"]
```

Update 3 [Jan 27] : I figured out the issue doesn't relate to my code or my yaml, at all. I have 02 **azure subscriptions**, one got the issue, one is working just fine with the same code, same deployment.yaml and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons for the pod to be crashing. The best way forward is to check the logs of your pod to see if crash comes from your application.

`kubectl logs aexp-5b5b7b6464-5lfz4 --previous`

Where `--previous` makes sure you can access the logs from the crashed pod.

If the log is empty you want to check your Dockerfile. It seems that the container does not have any long running process because it completed with a 'success' exit code:

```
Last State:   Terminated
Reason:       Completed
Exit Code:    0
```

Comment: I have edited the answer with more information is case the log is empty

Comment: thanks, I guess my pod has no problem, but I can not understand why I can run locally with Docker Desktop and even with "Bridge to Kubernetes" to see it up and run in AKS,  but it doesn't work with "kubectl apply". I have added my docker file.